# Are $B$ and $C$ the identity matrix?

Tags: matrices

If $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix, $B$ is $m\times m$ and invertible and $C$ is $n\times n$ and invertible.

Suppose $A=BAC$,does this follow that $B$ and $C$ are both the identity matrix?

Comment: Maybe consider $A = (kI) A \left(\frac1k I\right)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. For $m=n$, take for example $A$ be the identity matrix, $B$ any invertible matrix and $C=B^{-1}$.

Comment: Alright, thank u

Answer (score 0):

No. For example if $A=0$, then $A=BAC$ holds for any $B,C$.